# Understanding the syntax of "special cells" in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a part of my code that looks like this:

```
With Selection
    Set ConstantCell = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumber)
    Set FormulaCell = .SpecialCells(xltypeformulas, 21)
End With
```

It is part of a macro to color cells with different types of data in them. I understand what this part does but what I want to ask is what does the `21` represents? I found that in the syntax of this formula it represents some value and I thought that it would only select the cells which have formulas and equal to 21 but that was not the case when I ran the whole macro.

Comment: Read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like:

```
Set FormulaCell = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 21)
```

is the same as:

```
Set FormulaCell = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors + xlLogical + xlNumbers)
```

because:

> If *Type* is either ***xlCellTypeConstants*** or ***xlCellTypeFormulas*** , this argument is used to determine which types of cells to include in the result. These values can be added together to return more than one type. The default is to select all constants or formulas, no matter what the type.

and:

> ### ***XlSpecialCellsValue* constants**
>
> ```
> xlErrors     +16
>
> xlLogical     +4 
>
> xlTextValues  +2
>
> xlNumbers     +1
> ```

at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel

(also, `xlCellTypeFormulas` is misspelled in your example.)