# Why does this VBA code take too long to run?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

Hello Fellow community members!

This is a query related to VBA code optimisation and I am a beginner so I do not have much experience in this area. I am currently working on an excel file for building a dashboard and it required cleaning the data in the spreadsheet. So I wrote a very simple VBA code that successfully works but it takes an unusual amount of time to execute (40-45 mins). I researched on the internet regarding this but couldnt find a solution. I would be very happy if someone could help me with optimising the VBA code that I have created (posted below) so that it takes hopefully a maximum of 5 or 10 mins to execute or even faster. The code is simple where it deletes the entire row if the given criteria is matched in the specified range in a column. Thank you in advance for your help and I will be very grateful as I am a student working on this project!

VBA Code:

```
Sub Dashboard()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range, i As Integer

'Set range to evaluate
Set rng = Range("N8:N10000")

'Loop backwards through the rows in the range to evaluate
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

'If cell i in the range contains "x", delete the entire row
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "John" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete name Tom
Set rng = Range("L8:L10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "TOM" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Blanks
Set rng = Range("L8:L10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next


'Delete Blanks
Set rng = Range("O8:O10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Blanks
Set rng = Range("Q8:Q10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Blanks
Set rng = Range("R8:R10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Sara
Set rng = Range("R8:R10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "SARA" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Ben
Set rng = Range("R8:R10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "BEN" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Meredith
Set rng = Range("R8:R10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "MEREDITH" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete April
Set rng = Range("R8:R10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "APRIL" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Jason
Set rng = Range("R8:R10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "JASON" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Sana
Set rng = Range("R8:R10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "SANA" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Blanks
Set rng = Range("AJ8:AJ10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete June
Set rng = Range("AJ8:AJ10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "JUNE" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete October
Set rng = Range("AJ8:AJ10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "OCTOBER" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete January
Set rng = Range("AJ8:AJ10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "JANUARY" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'Delete Blanks
Set rng = Range("AS8:AS10000")
For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Cells(i).Value = "" Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Because it has a lot of loops. Make it one loop and check all your criteria in that single loop.

Comment: Your code simple wastes Excel resources. Only one iteration is enough, deleting one row at a time is time consuming, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce it to one loop only

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Dashboard()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    'Loop backwards through the rows in the range to evaluate
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 10000 To 8 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "N").Value = "John" Or _
           Cells(i, "L").Value = "TOM" Or _
           Cells(i, "L").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "O").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "Q").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "SARA" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "BEN" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "MEREDITH" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "APRIL" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "JASON" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "SANA" Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = "JUNE" Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = "OCTOBER" Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = "JANUARY" Or _
           Cells(i, "AS").Value = vbNullString Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Or even faster:
Collect all rows to delete in a variable and delete them all at once in the end:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Dashboard()
    Dim RowsToDelete As Range
    
    'Loop backwards through the rows in the range to evaluate
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 10000 To 8 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "N").Value = "John" Or _
           Cells(i, "L").Value = "TOM" Or _
           Cells(i, "L").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "O").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "Q").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "SARA" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "BEN" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "MEREDITH" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "APRIL" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "JASON" Or _
           Cells(i, "R").Value = "SANA" Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = vbNullString Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = "JUNE" Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = "OCTOBER" Or _
           Cells(i, "AJ").Value = "JANUARY" Or _
           Cells(i, "AS").Value = vbNullString Then
           
            ' collect rows we want to delete in RowsToDelete
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RowsToDelete = Rows(i).EntireRow
            Else
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, Rows(i).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    'delete all at once in the end
    If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
        RowsToDelete.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would guess that the runtime is not so much influenced by the multiple loops but by the Row-Deletion (in my experience, adding or removing row/columns is very slow compared to other actions). As a consequence, your 2nd version should be significantly faster.

Comment: @FunThomas Only those 17 loops without doing anything than checking the values (no deleting) take about 15 seconds already. But yes row-deletion has a huge impact if you don't at least turn off calculation, because the entire sheet needs to be calculated each row deletion.

Comment: It works beautifully! I tried both the solutions and they reduced the running time by a very big margin! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. It is compact, using a single iteration, an array to make the code faster and a `Union` range to keep cells of the rows to be deleted. These ones will be deleted at once, at the end of the code:

```
Sub Dashboard()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, arr, rngDel As Range, rngAdd As Range, i As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range("L1:AS1000").value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration

 For i = 8 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 3) = "John" Or arr(i, 1) = "TOM" Or arr(i, 1) = "" _
        Or arr(i, 4) = "" Or arr(i, 6) = "" Or arr(i, 7) = "" _
        Or arr(i, 7) = "BEN" Or arr(i, 7) = "SARA" Or arr(i, 7) = "MEREDITH" _
        Or arr(i, 7) = "APRIL" Or arr(i, 7) = "JASON" Or arr(i, 7) = "SANA" _
        Or arr(i, 25) = "" Or arr(i, 25) = "JUNE" Or arr(i, 25) = "OCTOBER" _
        Or arr(i, 25) = "JANUARY" Or arr(i, 34) = "" Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i))
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: From my experience, I think this approach is the fastest  , and I think OP should try at least @Maverick

Answer (score 1):

### A Bunch of `ElseIf` Statements

```
Sub FixDashboard()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If lCell.Row < 8 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Dont As Boolean
    
    For r = 8 To lCell.Row
        
        If StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "N").Value), "John", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "L").Value), "Tom", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "L").Value)) = 0 Then
        ElseIf Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "O").Value)) = 0 Then
        ElseIf Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "Q").Value)) = 0 Then
        ElseIf Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value)) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value), "Sara", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value), "Ben", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value), "Meredith", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value), "April", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value), "Jason", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value), "Sana", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "R").Value), "Tom", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "AJ").Value)) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "AJ").Value), "June", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "AJ").Value), "October", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf StrComp(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "AJ").Value), "January", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ElseIf Len(CStr(ws.Cells(r, "AS").Value)) = 0 Then
        Else
            Dont = True
        End If
        
        If Not Dont Then
            If drg Is Nothing Then
                Set drg = ws.Cells(r, "A")
            Else
                Set drg = Union(drg, ws.Cells(r, "A"))
            End If
        Else
            Dont = False
        End If
    
    Next r
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    drg.EntireRow.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you may use a helper column, you may benefit from deleting all rows at once:

```
Sub Dashboard()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Range("ZZ8:ZZ10000")
    .Formula = "=IF(OR(L8=""TOM"",L8="""",O8="""",Q8="""",R8="""",R8=""SARA"",R8=""BEN"",R8=""MEREDITH"",R8=""APRIL"",R8=""JASON"",R8=""SANA"",AJ8=""""," & _
        "AJ8=""JUNE"",AJ8=""OCTOBER"",AJ8=""JANUARY"",AS8=""""),""X"",1)"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    .ClearContents
End Sub

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code uses a helper column (in my code is ZZ but it can be anywhere) and types a formula of IG(OR...all your conditions). If any of those conditions is met, return "X" else return 1 (numeric value).

The formula will return a text or a numeric value depending on results. Then you may select **all** cells in that column that contains a formula returning a text (our X value) and delete all those rows at once.

Then the code clear the formula and leaves everything clean.

Advantages of this approach is that you don't loop at all and you delete all target rows at once. But disavantages is that if conditions changes frequently it can be annoying updating the code part.

Sources:

> [Understanding the syntax of "special cells" in Excel
> VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976521/understanding-the-syntax-of-special-cells-in-excel-vba)
>
> [Range.SpecialCells method
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.SpecialCells)